# XER encoded X.509 certs

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure

Would anyone happen to have an example of an XER encoded X.509 certificate so I can play around with it?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really a question, is it? I'm sure you could just create such a certificate with whatever library you choose... Besides, it's not really a security question, it's either a crypto question or a [sf] question.

Answer (score 2):

[X.509](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) states that certificates use DER encoding:

> For signature
> calculation, the data that is to be signed is encoded using the ASN.1
> distinguished encoding rules (DER)

Nominally, you *could* imagine that you encode the certificate data in XER, and that the DER encoding of the to-be-signed structure (`TBSCertificate`) is performed dynamically for purposes of computing or verifying the signature, but nobody does that because:

1. It would be very hard to do, because although DER is suposedly deterministic, there are an awful lot of details which can get wrong (do you use `UTCTime` or `GeneralizedTime` for the validity dates ? How do you handle milliseconds in the date representation ? For DN components, do you use `PrintableString`, `BMPString`, `UTF8String` ? Which kind of Unicode decomposition do you use for diacritics ? And so on). It would not be reliable.
2. XML encoding is awfully inefficient, both in space (it uses a lot of bytes, even when compared with Base64-encoded DER) and in CPU (that can be a tough issue with reduced platforms like smart cards).
3. Certificates are all about interoperability, and nobody supports XER-encoded certificates, so there is no added value in supporting them right now. There is no incentive either: what XML can bring (compared to DER) is automatic support of generic data transforms (XPath, XSLT... you name it), but that's the kind of thing that we *do not want* to do with certificates, because a certificate is *signed* and you cannot change a single bit of it without invalidating the signature.

If you want to play with signatures on XML data, lookup [XML-DSig](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/). It is noteworthy that when an XML-DSig object embeds a certificate (as an `X509Certificate` element), it uses [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding of the binary certificate (i.e., DER-encoded certificate)(see section 4.4.4).

**Summary:** there is no such thing as a "standard" XER-encoded *certificate* and I predict that it will take some time before such a thing appears (and I pray all the gods I know that it will not happen before I retire).